# I can't get Powershell to run my Notepad++ .py script

Tags: python, powershell, installation, notepad++

I am trying to teach myself how to code so I am Using the book Learn Python the Hard Way on my windows computer.

I downloaded Notepad++ and Python and my `python.exe` is understood by my computer, but I saved a Notepad++ file as `.py` and Powershell is saying that the file doesn't exist:

```
C:\Users\tmartinez6\python.exe: can't open file 'test1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How do I integrate my Notepad++ saved files such that when I try to run them in powershell they are found within my directory?

Comment: try to run it with the relative  path  (A relative path is a file path that's relative to your starting location in the file system.) and try to install python correctly it seams that you made a mistake on it

Comment: It seems that there may be a problem with how you installed Python. It was installed in you HOME directory (namely `C:\Users\tmartinez6`).

I suggest you install it in a better place. For example, if you installed Python 3.7.x, you can install it in  `C:\Python37\`

Comment: @HaceRopa Is it solved ?

Comment: Hi, yes. I was doing my command in the wrong directory lol